# Why is the Parameter Key for CITemperatureAndTint when creating a filter throwing an NSUnknownKeyException Error?

Tags: ios, swift3, cifilter

I wanted to modify the parameters for the CIFilter `CITemperatureAndTint`. From looking at the documentation, the 2 parameters I am interested in are both CIVectors, `inputNeutral` and `inputTargetNeutral`. I wanted to modify the inputNeutral vector, so I tried the following.

```
let point = CIVector(x: 6500,y :0)
//create instance of filter
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CITemperatureAndTint" )
filter!.setValue(6500, forKey: kCIInputNeutralTemperatureKey)
filter!.setValue(0, forKey: kCIInputNeutralTintKey)
filter!.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
let filteredImageData = filter!.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
```

For some reason, I get an NSUnknownKeyException for the two lines where I set the value for the filter and I don't know how to fix it. For the other parameter `inputTargetNeutral`, I had the same error. How can I fix it? The error I got was

```
2017-06-08 11:25:38.751 ImageProcessing[950:50758] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
reason: '[<CITemperatureAndTint 0x6000000cce80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key inputNeutralTemperature.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `kCIInputNeutralTemperatureKey` and `kCIInputNeutralTintKey` with `inputNeutral` and `inputTargetNeutral`, so that the setValue parts of the code will look something like this:

```
let inputVector = CIVector(x: 6500, y: 0) // arbitrary values
currentFilter.setValue(inputVector, forKey: "inputNeutral")
let targetVector = CIVector(x: 3000, y: 0) // arbitrary values
currentFilter.setValue(targetVector, forKey: "inputTargetNeutral")
```